# can't push, pull or do any git operations from xcode

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to use git from within Xcode, I'm in a bootcamp and no one can do it to work, we've tried to do it with Bitbucket and AWS code commit and the error that appears is

unexpected http status code 403(-1) and Authentication failed even if we double checked our info, anyone knows why this is? thank you!

Comment: Can you commit from the command line?

Comment: nope, it also shows me the same error :(

Comment: Are you in a corporate environment and behind a proxy?

Comment: nope, just normal connection

Comment: Is this your personal bitbucket? Or are you accessing a shared bitbucket where you don't have permissions granted on the repo

Comment: I have admin permissions on the repo, that's why is so weird :S even I created a repo to see if that was the issue and still no luck

Comment: When you're cloning the repo initially. How are you doing it?

Comment: I dont clone it, I create the repo in the pages of those services, and it is a clean repo, so when I want to upload the code so others can clone it, its when it prompts the error